Solving for unitary operation using perturbation theory
Let the time-dependent Hamiltonian be
\begin{equation}
H(t) = H_0(t) + \lambda H_1(t),
\end{equation} where $\lambda$ is a small parameter. In the interaction picture (i.e. rotating frame w.r.t unitary generated by $H_0(t)$), the unitary operation obeys the following Schrodinger equation:
\begin{equation}
i\dot{U_I}(t) = \lambda H_I(t) U_I(t), \quad H_I(t) = U_0^\dagger(t) H_1(t) U_0(t), \quad U_0(t) = \mathcal{T}e^{-i\int_0^t H_0(t') dt'}.
\end{equation} My objective is to solve $U_I(t)$ at final time $t = t_f$ using perturbation theory.
Following some references such as this one, since $\lambda$ is small, we can first express the unitary $U_I(t)$ as the power series of $\lambda$:
\begin{equation}
U_I(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^k U_I^{(k)}(t).
\end{equation} Substituting this into the Schrodinger equation above, we have the following equation:
\begin{equation}
i\partial_t(U_I^{(0)}(t) + \lambda U_I^{(1)}(t) + \lambda^2 U_I^{(2)}(t) + \dotsc) = \lambda H_I(t) (U_I^{(0)}(t) + \lambda U_I^{(1)}(t) + \lambda^2 U_I^{(2)}(t) + \dotsc).
\end{equation} Since the coefficients of each power of $\lambda$ must vanish, we have
\begin{align}
    i\partial_tU_I^{(0)}(t) = 0, \quad i\partial_tU_I^{(k)}(t) = H_I(t) U_I^{(k-1)}(t) \quad \forall k \geq 1,
\end{align} where we can assume $U_I^{(0)}(t) = I$ and $U_I^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all $k$.
Hence, we can iteratively solve the equation from $k=1, \dotsc$, to obtain $U_I^{(k)}(t_f)$. For instance, to solve for $k=1$, we have to solve:
\begin{equation}
i\partial_t U_I^{(1)}(t) = H_I(t) \quad \leftrightarrow \quad U_I^{(1)}(t_f) = -i\int_0^{t_f} H_I(t) dt. 
\end{equation} To find $U_I^{(2)}(t_f)$, we can solve:
\begin{equation}
i\partial_t U_I^{(2)}(t) = H_I(t) U_I^{(1)}(t), \quad U_I^{(1)}(t) = -i\int_0^t H_I(t')dt',
\end{equation} and so on. I hope what I explained is mathematically correct, but I am happy to be corrected and learn from my mistakes. Given the set-ups, here are my two inter-connected questions:
$\textbf{Question 1.}$
What is the benefit of using perturbation theory to find the unitary operation $U_I(t_f)$? The reason I am asking this is because it seems to me that to calculate $U_I^{(k)}(t_f)$, one needs to perform $k$-fold integrals, which is essentially the same cost when one tries to solve the unitary operation via Dyson or Magnus series.
$\textbf{Question 2.}$
Is there any special cases (e.g. $H_I(t)$ being a periodic Hamiltonian with the fact that I'm only interested in unitary at final time $t_f$ instead of arbitrary time $t$) where one can solve for $U_I^{(k)}(t_f)$ efficiently without invoking multi-integrals, or efficient iterative algorithm to solve the equation up to the desired order of $k$?
I know that this might be a research-level question, so I don't expect detailed answers. Instead, I would be very thankful if anyone could point me towards related research papers.

Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Let us for clarity review the derivation.

We start with the Hamiltonian in the Schrödinger (S) picture:
$$ H_S(t)~=~H_{0,S}(t)+V_S(t) .\tag{A}$$
Define evolution operators $U_0(t)$ and $U(t)$ satisfying
$$\begin{align}  i\hbar d_tU_0(t)~=~&H_{0,S}(t)U_0(t),\qquad U_0(t\!=\!0)~=~{\bf 1},\cr
i\hbar d_tU(t)~=~&H_S(t)U(t),\qquad U(t\!=\!0)~=~{\bf 1},\cr
U_0(t_2,t_1)~:=~&U_0(t_2)U_0(t_1)^{-1},
\end{align}\tag{B}$$
cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

Define the interaction (I) picture
$$\begin{align} A_I(t)~:=~&U_0(t)^{-1}A_S(t)U_0(t), \cr
U_I(t)~:=~&U_0(t)^{-1}U(t),\qquad U_I(t\!=\!0)~=~{\bf 1},\cr
i\hbar d_tU_I(t)~=~&U_0(t)^{-1}V_S(t)U(t)~=~V_I(t)U_I(t).
\end{align}\tag{C}$$
Here $A(t)$ denotes any operator that depends on only 1 time. One useful feature of the interaction picture is that if the perturbation $V_I(t)$ is small, then $U_I(t)$ is almost conserved in time.

The Schrödinger eq. (C) can be rewriten on integral form:
$$\begin{align} U_I(t)~=~&{\bf 1} -\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t \!ds~U_0(s)^{-1}V_S(s)U(s), \cr
U(t)~=~&U_0(t)-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t \!ds~U_0(t,s)V_S(s)U(s).
\end{align}\tag{D}$$

The last eq. (D) is a fixed-point equation that can be used repeatedly to generate a formula for $U(t)$ to higher and higher order in the perturbation $V_S$.
This in turn yields a perturbative formula for OP's sought-for quantity $U_I(t)=U_0(t)^{-1}U(t)$.
Alternatively, such formula follows by expanding the (anti)time-ordered exponential
$$\begin{align} U_I(t)~=~&(A)T\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t\! ds~V_I(s)\right]\cr
~=~&{\bf 1}-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t \!ds~V_I(s)+\ldots\cr
~=~&{\bf 1}-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t \!ds~U_0(0,s)V_S(s)U_0(s,0)+\ldots.\end{align}\tag{E}$$

The formula (E) has a nice graphical interpretation: At $n$th order we have to insert $n$ perturbations at all possible $n$-tuple of intermediate times. So OP is right: We cannot avoid multi-integrals.

The interaction picture is in practice only useful if $H_{0,S}(t)$ does not depend on time, and if the perturbation is of the form
$$ V_S(t)~=~f(t, z_S(t),\dot{z}_S(t),\ldots),\tag{F}$$
where $z_S(t)$ denote the fundamental dynamical variables of the theory (e.g. positions and momenta). Then
$$ V_I(t)~=~f(t, z_I(t),\dot{z}_I(t),\ldots),\tag{G}$$
i.e. we no longer have to refer to the Schrödinger picture.


